# Sort Column as a Row

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, string-manipulation, scripting, mathematica-online

I have

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 10};
b= {2, 3, 4, 8};
t= Do[If[a[[i]]+b[[i]]>3,Print[a[[i]]],"No"],{i,1,4}];
2
3
10
```

I need to get the result; t={2,3,10}

Comment: Use Table[] instead of  Do[]. And do not Print[].

Comment: Why does the title of your question say "Sort"? I dont see any attempt at sorting going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Do` does not produce an output. I'm not sure where you are on your Mathematica journey, but your code isn't very idiomatic for Mathematica. So, walking through a few things...

First, you can just add lists directly (assuming they're the same length):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 10};
b = {2, 3, 4, 8};
a + b
(* {3, 5, 7, 18} *)
```

Now, we can check which of these satisfies your condition:

```
GreaterThan[3] /@ (a + b)
(* {False, True, True, True} *)
```

If that looks like gobbledygook, then we need to back up and talk about mapping and "pure" functions. Anyway, with that new set of boolean values, we can choose the corresponding values in `a` using `Pick`:

```
Pick[a, GreaterThan[3] /@ (a + b)]
(* {2, 3, 10} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Among many other things,

```
Table[If[a[[i]] + b[[i]] > 3, a[[i]], Nothing], {i, 1, 4}]
Pick[a, UnitStep[a + b - 4], 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using `Do` (but, as others have pointed out, not really 'the Mathematica way')

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 10};
b = {2, 3, 4, 8};
t = Reap[Do[If[a[[i]] + b[[i]] > 3, Sow[a[[i]]]], {i, 1, 4}]][[2,1]];
t
(* {2, 3, 10} *)
```

Or, without using `If`

```
tt = Reap[Do[Sow[a[[i]]], {i, Flatten@Position[a + b, _?(# > 3 &)]}]][[2, 1]]

(* {2, 3, 10} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 10};

b = {2, 3, 4, 8};
```

A few more possibilities

Pre-define `c` for better readability

```
c = Transpose[{a, b}];
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[c, {x_, y_} /; x + y > 3 :> x]
```

> {2, 3, 10}

Using `GroupBy`

```
First /@ GroupBy[c, GreaterThan[3] @* Total][True]
```

> {2, 3, 10}

Using `Position` and `Extract`

```
p = Position[c, x_ /; Total[x] > 3, 1]
```

> {{2}, {3}, {4}}

```
Extract[p] @ a
```

> {2, 3, 10}

Using `SequenceCases` and `Riffle`

```
SequenceCases[Riffle[a, b], {x_, y_} /; x + y > 3 :> y]
```

> {2, 3, 10}